# How to make a k8s role that allows all operations on roles and rolebindings in a namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I want to make a role that allows to do any operation on "Roles" and "RoleBindings" (but not ClusterRoles or ClusterRoleBindings) on a namespace level.

This is the roles YAML I put together but when binding it to a service account it is now applied. What did I do wrong?

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: role-binder
  namespace: foo-namespace
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - Role
  - RoleBinding
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

Comment: The `verbs` should enumerate all the verbs, which are `- create - delete - deletecollection - get - list - patch - update - watch`.

Comment: My answer helped you to solve your problem? If yes consider [accepting and upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so the community can know my answer was helpful.

Comment: Star is not used in verbs to prevent SA from increasing it's privileges unintentionally and unnoticed when new privileges were added to the cluster by CRD or APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following rules:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: role-grantor
rules:
- apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["rolebindings"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
- apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["roles"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-grantor-binding
  namespace: office
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: role-grantor
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: employee
```

I tested it on my lab and it works as you desire:

```
$ kubectl --context=employee-context get role 
NAME                 AGE
deployment-manager   15m
role-binder          12m

$ kubectl --context=employee-context get rolebindings
NAME                         AGE
deployment-manager-binding   15m
role-grantor-binding         3m37s

$ kubectl --context=employee-context get clusterrolebindings
Error from server (Forbidden): clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "employee" cannot list resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

You can read more about this specifically in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#restrictions-on-role-binding-creation-or-update).